Percentage Change over multiple columns in R
I have an R dataframe where I'm trying to calculate % change across a number of columns, yet I can't seem to work out the correct syntax for it.
Basically I'm trying to calculate % change from a base date for column index 2:5 (column 1 is the Date).
What I've thought would work would be something like:
df <- df %>% mutate(across(2:5, ~ -first(2:5)/2:5))*100

Or something like that, but seemingly that's not correct. What can I try next?

How would you do it for just one column? Could you show a function for that

Always share a reproducible example of your data along with expected output to explain the issue that you are facing. It makes helping you faster and avoids confusion.
Based on my understanding of your explanation I think what you want is to calculate percentage change in values of a column as compared to 1st value in the same column. Using mtcars as an example this is how you can achieve that -
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% mutate(across(2:5, ~(. - first(.))/first(.) * 100))

#                    mpg cyl  disp     hp   drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4            21   0   0.0   0.00   0.00 2.6   16  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag        21   0   0.0   0.00   0.00 2.9   17  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710           23 -33 -32.5 -15.45  -1.28 2.3   19  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive       21   0  61.3   0.00 -21.03 3.2   19  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout    19  33 125.0  59.09 -19.23 3.4   17  0  0    3    2
#Valiant              18   0  40.6  -4.55 -29.23 3.5   20  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360           14  33 125.0 122.73 -17.69 3.6   16  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D            24 -33  -8.3 -43.64  -5.38 3.2   20  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230             23 -33 -12.0 -13.64   0.51 3.1   23  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280             19   0   4.7  11.82   0.51 3.4   18  1  0    4    4
#...
#...

